# STAN in R: Standard deviation or variance in normal distribution

Tags: r, bayesian, variance, stan

I'm using STAN in R to estimate some parameters.
For the priors I want to use a normal distribution.
In the model description the priors have to be determined:

```
     a ~ normal(mean,sigma)
```

Does STAN interpret the sigma as the standard deviation or as the variance?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Next time please first try checking [the manual](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/releases/download/v2.17.0/stan-reference-2.17.0.pdf) as this is readily available info.

Comment: @merv I did, but I couldn't find it in the 637 pages :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard deviation is the second parameter for the normal distribution in Stan.